# How do I install my wireless card driver offline

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, xubuntu, broadcom

I just installed `Xubunu 13.04`, but it didn't detect my wireless card.
This is my wireless card:

```
Broadcom Corporation:BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY: Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
```

I googled about it, and I found this solution :

> Once you have confirmed that your WLAN device is supported, you may
>   proceed to installing the driver by running the following command from
>   Terminal window.
>
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

The problem is that I can't run this command in a terminal because I've no connection in `xubntu`. I'm currently posting this thread from Windows.

I downloaded the package `firmware-b43-installer` from `debian`, and when I tried to install it, it told me that I need the `b43-fwcutter` package so I download it, and when I tried to install it the terminal shows me that the installation needs some sources from the internet.

I don't have an Ethernet or some other internet connection source, the only way I can access to internet is from Windows.

How can I install my wireless card driver offline ?

Comment: No idea .. ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it on Xubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal):

1. Download [firmware-b43-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/firmware-b43-installer) and [b43-fwcutter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/b43-fwcutter) from **Ubuntu**, choose the target release version (I chose Quantal) and architecture.

   - Alternatively, if you have a Live CD or installed *Ubuntu **of the same release** with Internet access, you can do: `apt-get -d install firmware-b43-installer` and then look for both packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Do not use packages from different releases.
   - Do not download from Debian. Being a derivative does not imply that they are compatible, and does not imply that Debian's packages are suitable for Ubuntu.
2. On the target machine, do `dpkg -i b43-fwcutter* && dpkg -i firmware-b43-installer*`

   - b43-fwcutter is a dependency of firmware-b43-installer, so it must be installed first.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the package you need is *linux-firmware-nonfree*. http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download

Please download the package, transfer it on a USB stick or similar to the desktop of the Xubuntu machine. Open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

```
sudo dpkg -i Desktop/linux*.deb
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

You should be all set.

Answer (score -1):

1:- After finish installation, Mount the installation media (dvd/usb) and open it.

2:- > pool > main > d > dkms > and 
     drag that package "**dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.1_all.deb**" on the desktop.

3:- Again open the media (dvd/usb)

4:- > pool > restricted > b > bcmwl > and 
     drag that package "**bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb**" on the desktop.

5:- Close all window and open terminal.

6:- Type in terminal without quotes " **cd \Desktop** " and hit enter.

7:- Now type in terminal without quotes " **sudo dpkg -i *.deb** " and hit enter.

8:- Type your password and wait for finishing installation.

9:- Restart your machine after finish above process.

Here is below link to step by step installation driver without Internet connection for BCM43xxx family branch.

[**BCM43xxx WiFi Driver Installation**](http://hafiz4saqib.blogspot.com/2016/11/bcm43142-wifi-driver-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.