# How to install wifi drivers from live Cd?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I have got Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop. I installed it long time ago and I made a lots of changes in it.

When I do `sudo lshw -C network` I get

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: e4:d5:3d:e4:df:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.43.151 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbe00000-fbe03fff
```

I ran Ubuntu 14.04 form Live CD and I ran the same command in the terminal `sudo lshw -C network`, and I get:

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan2
       serial: e4:d5:3d:e4:df:33
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.2.0-27-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.1.5 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

I would like to have the driver and the configuration from LiveCD in my installed operating system.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Simon - hello, here is a workaround (not offline) which was done for xubuntu, but is dealing with ubuntu-files with downloading them. Link to answer is : http://askubuntu.com/questions/304900/how-do-i-install-my-wireless-card-driver-offline

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `brcmsmac` on the installed system you can easily do it.

Run

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and it is done.

But I am not quite sure that this driver will work for this adapter.

Comment: After that command I got `configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.43.151 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg` so it didn't work correctly in my case

Comment: That is wierd. That command should remove the driver. Did it run without errors? And did you run the command from the installed system or LiveCD?